# Update from openSuSE 11.1 to openSuSE 11.4

Tags: updates, opensuse

Can I update my openSuSE 11.1 to 11.4 directly using an openSuSE 11.4 DVD? or will I need to upgrade to 11.2 and 11.3 first too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you're told not to try and skip version like that. It could work, but there's no way of knowing until you actually try it. This happens when you have third-party apps and proprietary drivers and stuff like that.

My opinion is to just upgrade the steps in between and save yourself a possible headache. You could mirror your /home directory in another partition as to not lose any of your data.

**Short answer:** at your own risk. I would go step by step.